# NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent in iOS9

Tags: ios, http, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm dealing with ATS in various iOSs versions.
Is there a way to whitelist the HTTP connections of webviews in iOS9 without using `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`?

For higher iOS's versions `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` just works fine, but I would like to avoid to disable ATS for all the HTTP connections in iOS9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878620/wildcards-on-ats-domain-exceptions/45878964#45878964 my answer here , maybe helpful.

Comment: Sadly, I don't know which URL is being called within the web view..

Please, upvote the question to give it some visibility

Comment: okay, I search online and find the only solution  in iOS9 is using  `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to disable ATS ..

Comment: yup, but I would like to avoid disabling ATS for the whole app in iOS9