# Byte array to UIImage

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin.iOS application, I have a byte array that I need to convert to a `UIImage`. I tried this:

```
var data = NSData.FromArray(myByteArray);
var uiimage = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
```

But it won't work. It creates the `UIImage`, but when I set it to a `UIImageView` I don't see anything. I used the same byte array on the Android platform of my project and it works fine. So I assume the way I try to convert it to a `UIImage` is wrong.

Comment: What type of image does `myByteArray` contain?

Comment: Could you show us how you got `myByteArray`, or at least the first/end bytes of `data`, since it's a JPEG, there should the be the corresponding StartOfFile/EndOfFile for .jpg. I don't use Xamarin, but could it be an issue of Big/LittleEndian?

Comment: @Larme it works on my Android platform so I don't think that is the issue here.

Comment: @Darius If apparently the issue was about `NSAllowsArbiraryLoads` was missing, then `myByteArray` would be nil. So clearly, checking the value of it could have point it that the issue is on the download part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you are downloading the data into a byte array, but here is an example of using `NSUrlConnection`:

```
// allow NSAllowsArbitraryLoads since this is a HTTP connection
var url = new NSUrl("http://example.com/foobar.jpg");
var data = NSUrlConnection.SendSynchronousRequest(NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(url), out var response, out var error);
var image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
ImageView1.Image = image;
```

Note: This is a synchronous request, use `SendAsynchronousRequest` or do this *off* the main thread.

> It was actually the NSAllowsArbiraryLoads permission that I was missing.

You can disable all ATS via `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
```

Preferable you can do it at the domain level:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45879443/4984832